# ViewPost.aspx displayed as title

Tags: web-part

At this moment I am playing with Sharepoint Online. We are using it for the intranet but I am stuck with a problem. We created a list with news posts, which is working fine. We show the 5 last created posts in a webpart as a list. At the beginning everything worked fine. But since the end of May we have some problems. Titles of (new created) articles in the list are being displayed as 'ViewPost.aspx'. This applies to new created posts and posts that are changed.

When I look in the source of the page I see this for the wrong articles: '\"Title\":\"ViewPost.aspx\",'. When I click on a news posts that redirects to a page to read the full article the title shows up good.

What could be the possible cause of this, I spend several hours to find the cause of this but I can't find anything.

The picture below shows the problem.

[image: Example of my problem.]

And if I click on the title to go to the post it's working fine:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After creating a map between a RefinableString and the Title field it's working again.